# Cannot load resource (ERR 500) lib.min.js when trying to hit the cloud run end point from browser

Tags: webpack, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a node app build with docker. The code runs absolutely fine on localhost and docker container (with docker run command) but when this is deployed to GCP cloud run it gives an error that it cannot load the lib.min.js file after I click on the url. This file called lib.min.js is a minified version of the website and is loaded in run time from github pages as specified in webpack.config.js. Debugging in the browser (when trying to hit the cloud run end point) I could see the other build files in the source (that were accessed locally from the repo itself (eg. chunks/gui.src) being loaded but only this file (lib.min.js) fails to load and it gives the 500 error. The gcp logs don't give any other extra information than the fact that this is a 500 error.

I tried to setup serverless vpc access and configured NAT to use static fixed outbound IP using the following link (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) as I thought the problem might be with cloud run instance not being able to access internet (outbound/egress traffic from the service due to dynamic IPs and hence not being able to load lib.min.js), but it did not help and the problem remained the same. Then, I added some firewall rules to allow all egress/ingress traffic through this service account but it did not help either. The app uses port 8601 and this is what is specified in the Dockerfile and the cloud run deployment as well.

Could the problem be somewhere else (eg. port or anything else) or I need to take some other steps? It would be great if someone could give any pointers.

(Also, just before this error there is a warning as well)

2022-06-12 18:20:44.712 IST

Warning: Response size was too large. Please consider reducing response size.

2022-06-12 18:20:44.713 IST

Error:GET 500 174 ms Chrome 81.0.4044.92 https://test-service-5ywoz37xea-uc.a.run.app/lib.min.js

Answer (score 0):

The `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header might be required for files larger than 32mb.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I get this error now, 502 (upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error), (I disabled http2 in deploy) webpack.config.js                                
     devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: process.env.PORT || 8601,
        // sockPort and disableHostCheck fix viewing over ssh tunneled ports, e.g. with gitpod.io
        sockPort: 'location',
        headers: {
          'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked' 
        },
        disableHostCheck: true
    }

Comment: enabling http2 gives same error

Comment: also works fine locally after the change (adding the header)

Comment: This 502 might be a proxy issue. Try to change `0.0.0.0` to `host.docker.internal` and/or `disableHostCheck` to `false`?

Comment: Actually, rather than setting the transfer encoding header (http1.1), I set, (http2: true) in the devServer (as cloud run documentation says that with http2 there are no size limits in request and response, so no 32 mb limits). Again ran fine locally and with docker run (with https, unsecure), also saw significantly faster load times. But when deployed to Cloud run it gives 503, service unavailable. Again tried with both http2 flag enabled and disabled. If this error could go away I guess it can work as size limit shouldn't be an issue then